# jQuery TableSort Plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using the tablesorting jquery plugin and I'm having a little bit of trouble with one thing.

I have a table that has 10 columns, I have a filter, that If I untick a box, removes the associated column from the table using CSS `display:none`.

This all works fine, but when I then use paging, these details are then displayed.

It seems that the table sorter plugin relaods the table data and displays all rows, even if they are set to `display:none`

Is there a way that if these columns are not shown / hidden, then when the paging is triggered these are not displayed?

Thanks

EDIT:

```
    $("#searchContainer #toggleOptions ul li a").on(

          {click: function()

                  {

                      //detect classes
                      var currentButtonCnt = $(this).parent().attr("class");
                      var currentState = $(this).attr("class");

                      //remove _btn
                      currentButton = "."+currentButtonCnt.substr(0, currentButtonCnt.length-4); 

                       var ids = [];
                      //toggle  
                      if(currentState == "ticked"){

                              $(currentButton).hide();
                              $(this).removeClass('ticked')

                      }else{

                              $(currentButton).show();  
                              $(this).addClass('ticked')

                      }

                 }

          }//end click 

    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the pager plugin for Tablesorter is swapping the `<td>` elements every time you switch pages for each row/column. I am guessing that your `display:none` style is only applied to the currently displayed `<td>` that you want to hide, so whenever you flip to the next page, the new `<td>` are flipped in, and are not affected by your `display:none` function.

Assuming that your function loops through your `<table>` and finds the right column of `<td>` to hide depending on which `checkbox` is checked, you should be able to fix your issue by calling your function that hides the appropriate columns `on click` every time you click the pager **next** and **previous** buttons.

**EDIT:**

You can add the Next and Prev button selectors to your function as follows:

```
//Add .next and .prev selectors here to your click function
$("#searchContainer #toggleOptions ul li a, .next, .prev").on(

          {click: function()

                  {

                      //detect classes
                      var currentButtonCnt = $(this).parent().attr("class");
                      var currentState = $(this).attr("class");

                      //remove _btn
                      currentButton = "."+currentButtonCnt.substr(0, currentButtonCnt.length-4); 

                       var ids = [];
                      //toggle  
                      if(currentState == "ticked"){

                              $(currentButton).hide();
                              $(this).removeClass('ticked')

                      }else{

                              $(currentButton).show();  
                              $(this).addClass('ticked')

                      }

                 }

          }//end click 

    )
```

It looks like the Tablesorter page plugin defaults the classes to `.next` and `.prev`. Check here: http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-pager.html and inspect the button elements.

Comment: I have amended my question with the code that is doing the removing of the columns. I'm not sure how I'd add the code to the next/previous buttons

Comment: Hi. Thanks for that. The issue I now have is that I get the following error in the console: `TypeError: currentButtonCnt is undefined`

Comment: Ah your code is looking for the parent of the button clicked. You'll have to modify the code for the Pager Prev and Next buttons, or else use a separate method to determine which columns have been selected.

Comment: The problem is, i need to call my code after the pager has loaded after clicking on prev/next. Is there a way of doing that easily?

Comment: Damn, looks like there's no nice API to play with for the pager plugin. You might have to hack the pager plugin source code itself... You could add your code to the `moveTo...` functions here: http://tablesorter.com/addons/pager/jquery.tablesorter.pager.js

Comment: Thought that might be the case. Any idea on how I'd add my code to these functions? I'm a JS n00b

Comment: Need to see more details like your HTML table structure and how you're using your classes to remove the columns. But basically it would be very similar to your logic that you have now, only that you need to select the classes that are to be removed from the previous/next functions instead of your checkbox.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34385/discussion-between-sipher-z-and-projeqht)